# Is react-app-rewire-mobx needed for create-react-app-typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, mobx

While searching online on how to use [Mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) with [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) (using react-scripts-ts) all suggestions point out to use [react-app-rewire-mobx](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/tree/master/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx) alongside react-app-rewire in order to support decorators.

However I've just created a simple Mobx app without using react-app-rewire-mobx and all I had to do was add `"experimentalDecorators": true` to `tsconfig.json`. The app runs fine and I can use all the Mobx decorators.

So my question is am I missing something critical by not using react-app-rewire-mobx that will manifest itself as I develop the app further? Or is it literally just for the decorators support? Why is react-app-rewire-mobx needed if TypeScript has a flag that allows decorators?

Is there anything crucial that I need react-app-rewire for when using Mobx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-app-rewired` allows to change `react-scripts` Webpack configuration and has a predefined set of helpers to configure Webpack loaders.

All that [`react-app-rewire-mobx`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/blob/63d2f60861fd468e018c0fce4920ad8787221417/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx/index.js) does is configuring Babel loader to use `transform-decorators-legacy` plugin.

Since Babel isn't needed in TypeScript setup and isn't used in `create-react-app-typescript`, `react-app-rewire-mobx` isn't needed.

`"experimentalDecorators": true` in tsconfig.json is the right way to use MobX with  `create-react-app-typescript`.

There is also [`react-app-rewire-typescript`](https://github.com/lwd-technology/react-app-rewire-typescript) that allows to configure original `react-scripts` to use TypeScript instead of using `react-scripts-ts` (`create-react-app-typescript`) fork.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that clears it up. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something important.

Comment: Found that version > 2.0 is not supporting `transform-decorators-legacy` any more.